# Are some facial features more important than others in human facial recognition?

Tags: perception, vision, recognition

I'm often surprised by the human ability to correctly identify other individuals despite significant modifications due to ageing, hairstyle, injury etc. But, sometimes the addition of a beard and a hat can radically increase the identification error.

- Are all facial regions  equally important when we try to recognise human faces?
- Do we focus more on some regions than others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a study by [Pelphrey et al., 2002](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/11189525_Visual_scanning_of_faces_in_autism/file/79e41506462f293e76.pdf) the authors show that when people are asked to scan a face, they spend about 80% of the time looking at the eyes, about 10% on the nose region, and a few percents on the mouth (the remaining few percentages were spent on other non-core features such as ears, forehead etc). **Hence, the eyes by far draw the most attention and represent the most important feature when it comes to facial processing**.

A typical example of a visual scan by a human subject as examined by eye tracking is the following (taken from [Pelphrey et al., 2002](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/11189525_Visual_scanning_of_faces_in_autism/file/79e41506462f293e76.pdf)), which shows that the subject scanned the core features of the facial image (eyes, nose, mouth):

[image: FaceScan]

Nonetheless, the presence of a complete face makes recognition more efficient than when looking at incomplete faces ([Tanaka & Farah, 1993](http://web.uvic.ca/psyc/vizcoglab/pubPDFs/Tanaka%26Farah.pdf))